# WooCommerce: How to automatically select variation attribute dropdown field when there is only 1 option?

Tags: variables, woocommerce, conditional-statements, product-variations

So I feel like this isn't too complicated of a request, but I simply can't figure it out. On my WooCommerce site, I have some variable products. There are 3 dropdown variation attributes in the following order (top to bottom): Color, Type, and Part Number. Each variation has a unique part number (only 1 part number per combination), so there is literally no need for the user to select the part number after they have chosen color & type. However, I need that part number to display for purposes of my product feed and so the customer can see the part number they have chosen by the previous 2 options.

My question is; since selecting a "Color" and "Type" narrows the final field ("Part number") down to only 1 option, how do I instruct WooCommerce to automatically select the single "part number" option that's available?

Comment: You can select default variation value while adding variations.

Comment: Yep, I've done that, but for all of the other combinations, the user will be required to select every option before being able to "add to cart". I want to essentially be able to set a locked in "part number" for each "color" and "type" combination. I want to arrange it so that the customer never has to manually select the "part number" field.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? Is there a js file with some simple script I can add to make the drop down select the only option automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with JS:

```
jQuery('a.toggle_component').click(function(e){
    if(!(jQuery(e.target).parents('.component').find('select.component_options_select > option[selected=selected]').val())) {
        jQuery(e.target).parents('.component').find('select.component_options_select > option:nth-child(2)').attr('selected','selected');
        jQuery(e.target).parents('.component').find('select.component_options_select').change();
    }
});
```